# How to make multiple full pages with image-background and scroll page to page

Tags: html, css, image

I'm pretty new to HTML & css. I'm working on something for school, I'd like to know how I could make pages with a full-screen background-image. I managed to succeed one page, but don't know how to proceed. I'd like to know how I can put another full-screen image beneath it. Also, how do you scroll the page to page? Not sure if this is a really dumb question but thanks for helping me out! PS: it is it possible with CSS only, haven't seen JS actually. Not sure if the code is running, it's not showing the picture to me, maybe wrong link!

```css
html{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 62.5%;
  height: 100%;
}

*, *:before, *:after{
  box-sizing: inherit;
 margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body{
  background-image: url(https://imgur.com/a/FZ3zD);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.container{
  width: 96rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.mainpage{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: 'Timmana', sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
}

.mainpage > h1{
 color: white;
 font-size: 10rem;
 font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

.mainpage > q{
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Old Standard TT', serif;
 font-size: 3rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/img/style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Amatic+SC|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Old+Standard+TT" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="mainpage">
        <h1>tentacion</h1>
        <q>Get lost here</q>
      </div>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest [Scrollify](https://projects.lukehaas.me/scrollify/) for that **scrolling page to page**. And for that multiple background image, you can wrap your contents in multiple div, each with different image.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I'll try that out!

Comment: I would advise using a plugin too, however if you want to do it yourself you should use `height:100vh` on the full screen containers which will make the div take the whole screen. It however doesn't have very good support on older browsers.

Comment: @GingerSquirrel `height:100%` on `body` and `html` tags is enough for full screen

Comment: Hi, @GingerSquirrel I tried this but the width is now too small, how do I make that the width is adjusted to full-screen as well ?

Comment: @Swellar Doesn't seem to work that way, I'm only getting like 75% of the height and 10% of the width :/

Comment: Most of the time it is enough, maybe there are conflicts within your styles

Comment: @Swellar It only shows the image behind the text